# Play Store CALL_LOG and SMS permissions not in APK but still showing in store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, android-permissions

I have a react-native app where I am trying to remove the CALL_LOG & SMS permissions but I am still seing the permissions asked in google play store.
[image: play store permissions screenshot]

I removed the permissions from my apk by adding the following lines in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_LOG" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SMS" tools:node="remove"/>
```

I also run the following command

```
aapt dump badging build\outputs\apk\foo-release.apk
```

to see what the final permissions requested are and I got the following

```
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='gr.coffeeisland.cimobileapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission: name='com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ'
uses-permission: name='com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE'
uses-permission: name='com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS'
uses-permission: name='com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT'
uses-permission: name='com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE'
uses-permission: name='com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE'
uses-permission: name='com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT'
uses-permission: name='com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE'
uses-permission: name='com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE'
uses-permission: name='com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS'
uses-permission: name='com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE'
uses-permission: name='com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS'
uses-permission: name='com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS'
uses-permission: name='me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ'
uses-permission: name='me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
```

So they are not supposed to be there! But they are!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no permission named `android.permission.SMS`. You would be looking for `READ_SMS`, `SEND_SMS`, or `WRITE_SMS`.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.